# Check if var is greater or lesser than and do assigned action

Tags: javascript

I have a small navigationSlider function:

```
    function navigateSlider(btnClicked) {

        if (btnClicked == 'next') {
            i++;
        } else {
            i--;
        }

        if (i > movies.length-1) {
            i = 0
        }

        var movie = movies[i].poster;
        document.getElementById('movie_slider').innerHTML = '<img src="' + movie + '"/>';
    };
```

This checks which button has been clicked and then adds 1 or subtracts 1 from the var i (starts at 0).

I want to be able to loop through the objects in the array so if you get to the last object in the array the var i should reset to the first object and when the user goes through the previous objects and gets to the first object var i should reset to the last object in the array so the user can loop through the list again and again. But I'm having trouble setting up the if statement for the last part.

In this part:

```
    if (i == movies.length) {
        i = 0
    }
```

There's a check to see if the i var is equal to the objects in the movies array and than it resets to 0 and the user can loop through the array again. But what would be a good solution for the opposite so that users can loop through the array using the previous button?

Comment: `if (i === -1) { i = movies.length - 1; }` You may want to look into the modulo operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this logic (you can avoid last if-condition)

```
if (btnClicked == 'next') 
{
  i = i == movies.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1 ;  
} 
else 
{
  i = i == 0 ? movies.length - 1 : i - 1 ;  
}
```

In simple if/else as you requested :)

```
if (btnClicked == 'next') 
{
  if ( i == movies.length - 1 )
  {
     i = 0;
  } 
  else
  {
     i++;
  }
} 
else 
{
  if ( i == 0 )
  {
     i = movies.length - 1;
  } 
  else
  {
     i--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks or the suggestion. I'm not really familiar with this notation of if/else, could you write it out as a simple if else statement?

Comment: Thanks, now I can see how the short notation works. In that notation do you use first `i = ` to set one of the two statements in the end? `0` or `i + 1 ` depending if `i == movies.length`?

Comment: It depends on the result of condition `i == movies.length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i > 0 && i < 8){
alert(i);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!